change matDatePicker color via custom theme
I am trying to change Angular Material-18, MatDatePicker component color via theme. I tried these lines, but no success. Need some help.
  @include mat.datepicker-color(m3-blue-theme.$light-theme, $color-variant: primary);
  @include mat.datepicker-theme(m3-blue-theme.$light-theme);

Html is like this
<mat-date-range-input id="range-picker" [max]="todayDate" [formGroup]="reportFormGroup.controls.dateRange" [rangePicker]="picker">
              <input
                matStartDate
                formControlName="startDate"
                placeholder="{{ 'START_DATE' | translate }}"
                readonly
                (focus)="picker.open()"
                (focusout)="onBlur()"
              />
              <input matEndDate formControlName="endDate" placeholder="{{ 'END_DATE' | translate }}" (focus)="picker.open()" readonly />
            </mat-date-range-input>

Thanks


what exactly do you want to change? plz share screenshot of output needed and scss file you are working with

I simply want that if my current theme is Green color, than the MatDatePicker should have green underline+greenicon. the code above is working for '@include mat.button-color(m3-blue-theme.$light-theme, $color-variant: primary);'

You can apply the below theme, the major changes are using datepicker-color and form-field-color for applying the green theme to the datepicker.
Note: Since the datepicker is attached to the body of the application, it's difficult to scope the datepicker popup color to the component level, ofcourse you can do it, by attaching the datepicker popup to the input and not the body, but for default scenario use this code.
The customization of the icon color, does not depend on the theme, so I use the manual override of the color style using mat-mdc-icon-button class.
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$green-palette,
    ),
  )
);

body {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  @include mat.datepicker-color($theme, $color-variant: tertiary);
  @include mat.form-field-color($theme, $color-variant: tertiary);
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

@include mat.core();
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($theme);
datepicker-overview-example {
  .custom-datepicker-colored.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-primary {
    .mat-mdc-icon-button {
      color: mat.get-theme-color($theme, tertiary) !important;
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

If you do not want to use all-component-themes then use the below method.
body {
  @include mat.core-theme($theme);
  @include mat.input-theme($theme);
  @include mat.form-field-theme($theme);
  @include mat.datepicker-theme($theme);
  @include mat.icon-button-theme($theme);
  @include mat.datepicker-color($theme, $color-variant: tertiary);
  @include mat.form-field-color($theme, $color-variant: tertiary);
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

Stackblitz Demo

Its working for sure. But for some reason I dont want to use  '@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);'. It is possible to make this code work without the above line.

@raju updated my answer!
